# Convert 3D array to cell of 2D arrays

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I use octave, but matlab users will probably be just as helpful.

I have an an array defined in space `m x n`  and in time, `t`. Therefore it has size `m x n x t`. For a certain function, it would be much more helpful to convert this 3D dimension into a cell with the following structure:

Consider `A` to be the `m x n x t` array.

`cell = {A(:,:,1), A(:,:,2), ..., A(:,:,t)}`, that has `t` element, each element an `m x n` array.

I don't know how to do this for dynamic `t`.

Comment: Check out [`mat2cell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mat2cell` to achieve it:

```
[m n t] = size(A);
B=mat2cell(A, m, n, ones(1,t));
```